# Can React's PureComponent use `setState`?

Tags: reactjs

I was told that React's pure components can have `state` and can change it with `setState`. It feels wrong for a component with state to be called "pure". Is it correct? If so how is it pure with a state?

If it matters I am talking about class-based components extending from the `PureComponent` class and using the `setState` method

Comment: @camden_kid I was talking about class-based components

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the state in the normal way with the pure components:

```
class Demo extends React.PureComponent {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        hello: 'world'
    };
}
...
```

By default, a plain React.Component has shouldComponentUpdate set to always return true. This is good because it means React errs on the side of always updating the component in case there’s any new data to show. However, it’s bad because it means React might trigger unnecessary re-renders. One way to deal with these extra re-renders is to change the shouldComponentUpdate function to check when your component needs to update.

Another way to stop extra re-renders is to use a PureComponent: [more info](https://lucybain.com/blog/2018/react-js-pure-component/)

Comment: Then maybe it's a bit of a misnomer? We call functions pure if they never make any side-effects. `setState` seems to be a side-effect. That's what makes me feel it's odd.

Comment: Yes, but `PureComponent` is a class, not a function, so I think “pure” doesn’t apply in the same manner. Since it’s actually about idempotency, maybe a better name would have been `IdempotentComponent`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can.

It's pure concerning props *and* state, i.e. if both of those stay the same, no re-render occurs.

Quoting [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent):

> If your React component’s `render()` function renders the same result given the same props and state, you can use `React.PureComponent` for a performance boost in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

There’s nothing wrong with using component state on a `PureComponent`, as far as I know.

After all, extending from `PureComponent` only adds an implementation of `shouldComponentUpdate`. That shouldn’t really interfere with anything in your component state.